# Social Networking Site with Grails and Neo4j

Tags: grails, neo4j, grails-orm, social-networking, graph-databases

I am developing a social networking website with Grails and MYSQL DB. But I am planning to move to Neo4j DB. Grails supports complete GORM features with MYSQL. But I am sure about the same features in Neo4j. There is a Grails plugin for Neo4j which does not support some of the features that is required to support big websites. So I am planning to use the native Neo4j API. From Grails how to connect to Neo4j DB? There are two scenarios in my case.

Case 1:
Neo4j server is up and running. How to connect and perform the database transactions?

Case 2:
Neo4j server is not running. How to connect and perform the database transactions? I was able to connect using GraphDatabaseService class. But why would one need to connect to DB which is not running. What is this class GraphDatabaseService particularly used for?

I want to use the native Neo4j API to get access to maximum features. Is there a better approach to build the application.

Answer (score 0):

The Grails Neo4j GORM plugin in version 2.0.0.M01 is able to run embedded mode only - so the JVM running the Grails applications spawns the database inside the same JVM. Next milestone (M02) will add support for accessing Neo4j via REST.
In case you don't want to transparently use the GORM methods to talk to Neo4j you can always use direct access by emitting Cypher statements or accessing GraphDatabaseService directly (only on embedded mode of course).

Comment: When can we expect the next milestone release Stefan?